# Why this if statement is being skipped?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Can anyway tell me why the following if statement is being skipped?
I want to check if my mAlphabetCode contains 0-9 literal, not 0 to 9.

```
        // check if alphabet code is numeric
        if (mAlphabetCode.equals("0-9")){
            mAlphabetCode = "-";
        }
```

Here is the whole code:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if (parent.getId() == R.id.lv_gl_content) {
        // store data to be pass
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, AchList.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("mPageUrl", mGameList.get(position).getItemPageUrl());
        mIntent.putExtra("mGameTitle", mGameList.get(position).getTitle());

        // start activity and page animation
        startActivity(mIntent);
        mPageTrans.slideIn();

    } else if (parent.getId() == R.id.lv_alphabet_content) {
        // get alphabet code
        String mAlphabetCode = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString().toLowerCase();

        // check if alphabet code is numeric
        if (mAlphabetCode.equals("0-9")){
            mAlphabetCode = "-";
        }

        // build page url
        mGameListUrl = mGameListUrl.substring(0, (mGameListUrl.length() - 2) ) + mAlphabetCode + "/";

        mAlphabetMenu.setItemChecked(position, true);

        // close browsing menu
        mSlidingPane.closePane();

        // make network request
        mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, mGameListUrl, onSuccess(), onError());
        mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
    }
}
```

And here is what the debugger saying that mAlphabetCode contains before hitting the if statement:

[image]

My error was here in my strings.xml file:

```
    <!-- strings of arrays -->
<string-array name="slide_menu_alphabet">
    <item>0&#8211;9</item>
```

I had changed the item from 0-9 to 0 &#8211 ;9 (spaced so numbers show) as AndroidStudio IDE subjected and thanks to @user1873880 and David Cesarino, I changed to 0 &#45 ;9 (spaced so numbers show) and now it works great.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe he wants it this way since his debugger shows that his String contains the "0-9" literal. EDIT: In response to deleted comment about @Twenty40 wanting to check for individual digits 0 through 9 as opposed to the stated literal.

Comment: Yes, I want to check if my mAlphabetCode contains 0-9 literal, not 0 to 9. edit question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that '-' character in your code is in fact has integer number 45, while in the debugger it's 8211, which mean that it is different character. You can verify this via some logs, just try to see this value `(int) '-'`.

Comment: This is the only correct response in my opinion. I believe that ASCII 8211 is the double-dash, looks like a slightly longer dash.

Comment: Exactly. Since he answered first (fair to be accepted), I will add the details here: the en-dash (#8211, "–") is very well known in typographic circles, and is very different (computing and semantically) than the hyphen ("-") that we normally type with the keyboard key (- and = key). For example, Lint rules are paying a lot of attention to that, and it's very common to retrieve an en-dash from XML strings thinking it's an hyphen (frequent source of confusion that I see). In this case, he is writing his code using the keyboard key (hyphen), but comparing against a String with a dash. :-)

Comment: By the way… I'm a typography freak. Did you notice? ;-)

Comment: that's noticeable for sure :)

Comment: still do not get how to fix it. I can get around it by changing the if (mAlphabetCode.equals("0-9")) to if (mAlphabetCode.contains("0")) but i do not like this workaround. it used to work fine before and now it don't work.

Comment: @Twenty40 it "used to work" because the data source was probably using the "keyboard hyphen" before, but not anymore. If you want to cover all your bases, compare to a RegEx made of "0", the hyphen-like characters you want to consider, and "9". Semantically speaking, you'd be safe including, in your RegEx, the _hyphen-minus_ (0x002D), the _hyphen_ (0x2010), the _non-breaking hyphen_ (0x2011), the _figure dash_ (0x2012) and the _en-dash_ (0x2013). I use these a lot, so I'm sure there are folks out there using them as well. _em-dash_ and _horizontal bar_ are probably not needed in this case. ;-)

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to go crazy with hyphens. I posted the above comment not to show my hyphen addiction, but to tell an answer semantically correct (i.e., a comparison that achieves exactly the meaning you are looking for). You may — _may_! — be just fine checking just the first and third characters to "0" and "9" since the second will _probably_ be _some_ kind of separator you want, _in this particular case_.